# Killing a SparkContext so I can create a new one

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, rdd

Been trying to run a Jupyter Notebook setup for pyspark v2.1.1, but every time I try instantiating a context (freshly restarted kernel and derby.log file and metastore_db dir were deleted), I get the following error telling me a context is already running.

```
ValueError: Cannot run multiple SparkContexts at once; 
existing SparkContext(app=PySparkShell, master=local[16]) created by 
<module> at /home/ubuntu/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/IPython/utils/py3compat.py:289
```

I've tried restarting the kernel and deleting the derby.log and also attempted to load that context by the app name and master it gives in the error, and then stop the context to no avail:

```
sc = SparkContext(app='PySparkShell', master='local[16]')
sc.stop()
```

Has anyone had this problem and know how to just get a context running in a Jupyter Notebook when this happens?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So instead of figuring out how to kill the Spark Context already running, apparently you can "get" (or "create") an already created context by calling

```
from pyspark import  SparkContext
sc = SparkContext.getOrCreate()
```

at the beginning of your jupyter notebook.

Comment: I think `getOrCreate` is available with `SparkSession` and not `SparkContext`

Comment: I thought the same, but tried it and it worked for my RDD based ALS model. Maybe it's a new thing since at least v2.1.1?

Comment: I was wrong, it's always been there : https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/SparkContext.scala#L2506